# Python - Search and export information from JSON

Tags: python, json

This is the structure of my json file

```
 },
    "client1": {
        "description": "blabla",
        "contact name": "",
        "contact email": "",
        "third party organisation": "",
        "third party contact name": "",
        "third party contact email": "",
        "ranges": [
            "1.1.1.1",
            "2.2.2.2",
            "3.3.3.3"
        ]
    },
    "client2": {
        "description": "blabla",
        "contact name": "",
        "contact email": "",
        "third party organisation": "",
        "third party contact name": "",
        "third party contact email": "",
        "ranges": [
            "4.4.4.4",
            "2.2.2.2"
        ]
    },
```

I've seen ways to export specific parts of this json file but not everything. Basically all I want to do is search through the file using user input. 
All I'm struggling with is how I actually use the user input to search and print everything under either client1 or client2 based on the input? I am sure this is only 1 or 2 lines of code but cannot figure it out. New to python. This is my code

```
data = json.load(open('clients.json'))

def client():
    searchq = input('Client to export: '.capitalize())
    search = ('""'+searchq+'"')
    a = open('Log.json', 'a+')
    a.write('Client: \n')

client()
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to search for? Can you give an example of a query and the desired result?

Comment: I want to be able to search for "client1",  and have that store in a variable I can append to a new file, it should include all fields under client1, appreciate any help I can get!!

Comment: So you want the user to type "client1" and then get the information for "client1" from the JSON?

Comment: look at the python docs on dealing with json https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going:

```
# Safely open the file and load the data into a dictionary
with open('clients.json', 'rt') as dfile:
    data = json.load(dfile)

# Ask for the name of the client
query = input('Client to export: ')

# Show the corresponding entry if it exists,
# otherwise show a message
print(data.get(query, 'Not found'))
```

Comment: That is brilliant thank you! Just have to figure out how to not make pprint sort the fields in alphabetical order and append this to a new file! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that. If it helped you, please consider upvoting/accepting the answer. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, thanks again and thank you to everyone else who helped. Great community.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to preface this by saying this is 100% a drive-by answering, but one thing you could do is have your user use a . (dot) delimited format for specifying the 'path' to the key in the dictionary/json structure, then implementing a recursive function to seek out the value under that path like so:

```
def get(query='', default=None, fragment=None):
    """
    Recursive function which returns the value of the terminal
    key of the query string supplied, or if no query 
    is supplied returns the whole fragment (dict).

    Query string should take the form: 'each.item.is.a.key', allowing
    the user to retrieve the value of a key nested within the fragment to
    an arbitrary depth.

    :param query: String representation of the path to the key for which
    the value should be retrieved
    :param default: If default is specified, returns instead of None if query is invalid
    :param fragment: The dictionary to inspect
    :return: value of the specified key or fragment if no query is supplied
    """
    if not query:
        return fragment

    query = query.split('.')

    try:
        key = query.pop(0)

        try:
            if isinstance(fragment, dict) and fragment:
                key = int(key) if isinstance(fragment.keys()[0], int) else key
            else:
                key = int(key)
        except ValueError:
            pass

        fragment = fragment[key]
        query = '.'.join(query)
    except (IndexError, KeyError) as e:
        return default if default is not None else None

    if not fragment:
        return fragment

    return get(query=query, default=default, fragment=fragment)
```

There are going to be a million people who come by here with better suggestions than this and there are doubtless many improvements to be made to this function as well, but since I had it lying around I thought I'd put it here, at least as a starting point for you.

**Note**:
Fragment should probably be made a positional argument or something. IDK. Its not because I had to rip some application specific context out (it used to have a sensible default state) and I didn't want to start re-writing stuff, so I leave that up to you.

You can do some cool stuff with this function, given some data:

```
d = {
    'woofage': 1,
    'woofalot': 2,
    'wooftastic': ('woof1', 'woof2', 'woof3'),
    'woofgeddon': {
         'woofvengers': 'infinity woof'
    }
}
```

Try these:

```
get(fragment=d, query='woofage')
get(fragment=d, query='wooftastic')
get(fragment=d, query='wooftastic.0')
get(fragment=d, query='woofgeddon.woofvengers')
get(fragment=d, query='woofalistic', default='ultraWOOF')
```

Bon voyage!

Answer (score 0):

Pass the json format into Dict then look into the topic you want and Read or write it

```
import json
r = {'is_claimed': True, 'rating': 3.5} 
r = json.dumps(r) # Here you have json format {"is_claimed": true, "rating": 3.5}
```

Json to Dict:

```
loaded_r = json.loads(r) # {'is_claimed': True, 'rating': 3.5}

print (r)#Print json format
print (loaded_r)  #Print dict
```

Read the Topic

```
Data=loaded_r['is_claimed'] #Print Topic desired
print(Data) #True
```

Overwrite the topic

```
loaded_r['is_claimed']=False
```

And also this would do the same

```
print(loaded_r['client1']['description'])
```

[image]